# How to use Kibana charts in web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, kibana-4

I just started to learn Kibana and is it possible to show the kibana charts in our own web application like a plug in. As far as what I have understood Kibana is like a service which connects to ES index and process data based on our queries and filters and show in a nice diagrammatic way.
So is there any way where we can create a similar thing in the web app we are developing. Mine is a web app purely written in JQuery

Comment: You have here http://www.first8.nl/blog/controlling-a-kibana-dashboard-with-a-custom-form/ a nice try